# Issue with React Virtualized Select css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux, react-virtualized

I'm trying to use React Virtualized Select https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select for drop down and my react component code is here

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var SearchActions = require('../actions/SearchActions');
var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');
var Utils = require('../utils/Utils');
var SearchAccountSelector = require('./SearchAccountSelector');
var queryString = require('query-string');
var SearchHint = require('./SearchHint');
var VirtualizedSelect = require('react-virtualized-select').default;
module.exports = React.createClass({
    componentName: 'Search',
    getDefaultProps() {
        return {};
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: false,
            authenticated: false,
            visible: true,
            data: null,
            showAccountSelection: false,
            selected: null,
            search: '',
            optionPartnerList: []

        };
    },

    componentDidMount () {
        var qS = queryString.parse(location.search);
        if (qS && qS.search) {
            this.setState({search: qS.search, visible: true});
        }

        this._unsubscribe = AppStore.listen(Utils.createRefluxComponentDispatcher(this));
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        if (this.refs.inputSearch) {
            this.refs.inputSearch.focus();
            this.refs.inputSearch.select()
        }
    },

    componentWillUnmount () {
        this._unsubscribe();
    },

    [AppStore.events.onSecurityCheck] () {
        console.log('onSecurityCheck', arguments);
        this.setState(function (prev, cur) {
            var st = {
                authenticated: AppStore.authenticated
            };
            if (!AppStore.authenticated) {
                st.async = false;
            }
            return st;
        });
    },

    [AppStore.events.onAccountSearch] (data) {

        var accountsNum = data.errorMessage ? 0 : this.numberOfAccountsFound(data);
        var state = {
            async: false,
            data: data.errorMessage ? {} : data,
            showAccountSelection: false,
            selected: null,
            error: null
        };
        console.log('[' + accountsNum + '] accounts found when search completed', data);

        if (accountsNum == 0) {
            state.error = data.errorMessage ? data.errorMessage : 'No accounts found';

        } else if (accountsNum == 1) {
            // if there is single account found selecting it and closing search panel
            state.selected = this.getFirstKey(data);
            state.visible = false;
            AppActions.selectAccount(state.selected);// auto select account if there is no ambiguites
            SearchActions.cDVR({query: state.selected});
        } else {
            // if multiple account found lets user select a correct one
            state.showAccountSelection = true;

        }

        this.setState(state);
    },

    [AppStore.events.onSelectAccount]() {
        if (AppStore.isValidUserProfile()) {
            this.setState({
                visible: false
            });
        }
    },

    [AppStore.events.onLogin]() {
        //Handling properly case when session is timed out so user will return to previos screen
        if (!this.state.selected) {
            this.setState({
                visible: true
            });
        }
    },

    [AppStore.events.onLogout](event) {
        if(!event || !event.byTimeout){
            this.setState({   data: null,
                showAccountSelection: false,
                selected: null,
                search: ''
            });
        }
    },
    [AppStore.events.onResized](windowSize){
        this.setState({width: windowSize.innerWidth, height: innerHeight})
    },


    numberOfAccountsFound(data) {
        var size = 0, key;
        if (!data) {
            return size;
        }
        for (key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
        }
        return size;
    },

    getFirstKey(data){
        for (let key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) return key;
        }
    },

    handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.refs.searchHint.removePopover();
        console.log('clicked event', event);
        this.setState({
                data: null,
                async: true,
                error: null
            }
        );
        var query = this.refs.inputSearch.value.trim();
        this.setState({search: query});
        if (query) {
            //extract receiver Id from Recording Id, by extracting string between V&L or A&L
            AppActions.resetFieldsForNewSearch();
            var receiverIdPattern = new RegExp('(V|A)(.*?)L');
            var parsedReceiverId = receiverIdPattern.exec(query);
            if (parsedReceiverId != null && parsedReceiverId[2] != null) {
                let receiverId = parsedReceiverId[2];
                AppActions.setSearchQuery(query);
                //use receiverId to perform search
                query = receiverId;
            } else {
                AppActions.clearRecIdSearch();
            }
            SearchActions.cDVR({query: query});
            AppStore.selectedPartner = '';
            SearchActions.search({query: query});
            Utils.updateQueryString('search', query);
        } else {
            this.setState({async: false, error: 'Invalid Input'});
        }
    },

    openNav(){
        this.setState({visible: true});
        AppActions.hideBodyScrollBar();
    },
    closeNav(){
        this.refs.searchHint.refs.popover.close();
        this.setState({visible: false});
        AppActions.showBodyScrollBar();
    },

    searchIcon(){
        if (this.state.authenticated) {
            return (<span id="search" onClick={this.openNav}><i className="fa fa-search search-icon pointer" style={{fontSize: '1.4em'}}/></span>);
        }
    },

    getOptions(partnerList) {
        let options = partnerList.map( x => ({value :x,label: x}));
        return options;
    },

    errorRender() {
        let style = this.state.error ? {visibility: 'visible'} : {visibility: 'hidden'};
        return (
            <div style={style} className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <i className="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> {this.state.error}
            </div>);
    },

    toggleOverlayStyle(state){
        this.setState({overlayOverflowY : state});
    },
    [AppStore.events.onResized](windowSize) {
        let state = AppStore.innerHeight < 900 && this.refs.searchHint && this.refs.searchHint.state.showSearchHint ? 'auto' : 'hidden';
        this.toggleOverlayStyle(state);
    },
    [AppStore.events.onPartnersAllowedUpdated](partnerList) {
        this.optionPartnerList = this.getOptions(partnerList);
    },

    render: function () {
        var self= this;
        if (!this.state.authenticated) {
            return null;
        }
        let componentDisabled = this.state.async ? true : false;
        let buttonIcon;
        let closeButton = AppStore.selectedAccount ?
            <a href="#" className="closebtn" onClick={this.closeNav}>&times;</a> :
            (<a key="-1" className="logout-link dropdown-item t-font" onClick={AppActions.logout} href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-sign-out m-r-10"></i>Logout</a>);

        let overlayStyle = {width: this.state.visible ? '100%' : '0px', display: this.state.visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'overflowX': 'hidden', 'overflowY': this.state.overlayOverflowY};
        if (this.state.visible) {
            AppActions.hideBodyScrollBar();
        } else {
            AppActions.showBodyScrollBar();
        }

        if (!this.state.async) {
            buttonIcon = <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
        } else {
            buttonIcon = <i className="fa fa-cog fix fa-spin"></i>
        }
        //TODO: refactor this make it css driven using flex box
        let style = {top: '37%'};
        if (this.state.data && Object.keys(this.state.data).length > 1) {
            style = {top: '10%'};
        }
        return (

            <div style={{float:'left'}} className="search-div">
                {this.searchIcon()}
                <div className="overlay" style={overlayStyle}>
                    {closeButton}
                    <div className="global-search center-content-wrapper" style={style}>
                        <form id="searchFormComponent" ref={function(){$('#searchFormComponent').show('fast')}}
                              className="global-search" onSubmit={this.handleClick} style={{height: '500px'}}>
                            {this.errorRender()}
                            <div className="f-row f-center">

                                <VirtualizedSelect
                                    options={self.optionPartnerList}
                                    onChange={(selectValue) => this.setState({ selectValue })}
                                    value={this.state.selectValue}
                                />
                                <button id="searchbutton" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block t-font f-1"
                                        disabled={componentDisabled}
                                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                                        style={{ paddingLeft: '4px',paddingRight: '4px', fontSize:'1.1em',marginLeft:'500px'}}>
                                    {buttonIcon}
                                </button>

                            </div>
                            <SearchAccountSelector data={this.state.search == ''? {}: this.state.data}/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

this is how i included in package.json

```
"react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dimensions": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-virtualized-select": "3.1.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^1.2.12",
```

i have also included the css as below as per https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select#simple-example

[image]

i have included the css in my main.jsp

[image]

but facing an issue where the drop down doesn't load properly when showing "No results found"

Any help in fixing the css will be of great help 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`react-virtualized-select` is using `react-select` to render select element. So try changing `.Select-menu-outer` width. Set `width=100%`.

Please make sure that `react-select.css` is loaded.